# JSF commandLink not working on redirected error page

Tags: jsf, exception, commandlink

I'm redirecting all exceptions to a simple error page with the following entry in my web.xml file:

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
  <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

My error page contains:

```
<ice:form id="errorForm">
  <ice:outputText value="#{guiProps.UnknownError}"/><br/><br/>
  Click <ice:outputLink value="/"> here</ice:outputLink> to attempt to return to the previous page.<br/>
  Click <ice:commandLink value=" here" action="#{UserBean.logoutAction}"/> if you are unable to do so.
</ice:form>
```

The problem is, the commandLink DOES NOT work when it's clicked.  The logoutAction method is never fired.  You get a brief hourglass, I observe a little bit of XMR action (via Chrome browser) but nothing really happens.  I've also tried using vanilla JSF tags (h:commandLink, h:form, etc) and the same thing happens, so its a JSF problem, not an ICEfaces problem

Also weird...this problem only happens using Glassfish v2.1.1, not v2.1.  I don't know if it's a v2.1.1 bug, per se, but in any case, if there is a way to work around it or a way of figuring out what is going on, I'd appreciate any help, because we are certainly using v2.1.1.

Comment: To avoid the obvious: are you sure that the form is not nested inside another form? Check generated HTML output to be sure.

Comment: Nope.  It's only a single form.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is supposed to be `UserBean` and not `userBean`?

```
#{userBean.logoutAction}
```

Comment: Yup, the spelling is correct.  Like I said, I have this working as my "logout" button on all of my pages...it's just not working on this error page.

Comment: Hmm, then perhaps this is a bug in Glassfish only